# How to avoid running a specific task simultaneously in Luigi with multiple workers

Tags: python, matplotlib, luigi

I use Luigi to build data analysis tasks including plotting by matplotlib.

It seems concurrent runs of matplotlib plotting causes a problem, which causes returning from the task prematurely, doing nothing, for some reason. (Looks like this is the problem with matplotlib, though I might be wrong.)

To solve this issue, I want to avoid running multiple workers for only that plotting task simultaneously, while running other tasks in multiple workers. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [resources](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/blob/0a3797911425f6f16812ac441f14c4e5e0a2e4c8/doc/configuration.rst#resources) for that. On `/etc/luigi/client.cfg` configure a resource like:

```
[resources]
mathplotlib: 1
```

And then, modify your task this way:

```
class MyTask(luigi.Task):
    resources = {"mathplotlib": 1}
```

If you have muliple machines running luigi workers and you want that only one worker across all machines may be using a given resource, then you can take a look a [this solution](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/issues/1162#issuecomment-151592029).